# Up-vote red highlight not showing

Tags: bug, android-app

I up-voted an answer but the red highlight around the up arrow never came as can be seen below.

[image]

To make sure, I voted again and got the error message.

[image]

Comment: On a side note: please don't upvote answers to questions caused by typographical errors.  Such questions can be answered in the comments, closed, and deleted.  Answering slows it down ... because the answers get upvoted.

Comment: Old bug that I'm afraid will never be fixed.

Comment: @zondo: Please _never_ answer in the comments.

Comment: @Lightness: I answer to help the OP, but I use a comment so that the question can be deleted easily.  Which would you rather, the OP doesn't get his answer, or Stack Overflow has a useless question?

Comment: @zondo: How do you know that what you write is "his answer"? When you post your answer as a comment, you bypass every single one of the site's quality control measures (voting, review, editing), and might be giving them a _wrong_ answer. Peer review is one of the fundamental tenets of this community; it is not optional. If the question does not deserve an answer, then it does not deserve an answer, period! Simply don't post one. Certainly don't do so in the wrong place :(

Comment: @Lightness: I can understand your view that such questions shouldn't be answered, but I can imagine how annoying it would be for the OP to have his question closed as a typo without knowing what the typo is.  Posting it as an answer is sure to get at least one upvote, and that slows down the deletion process.  Therefore, the best way that I see of helping the OP is to post a comment.  Closing the question is not because it doesn't deserve an answer; it's because it won't help future readers.

Comment: @zondo: If we were to prioritise the needs of every OP with a typo-driven question over the quality standards we have in this community, Stack Exchange would be just another message board or forum. It is quite deliberately not either of those things. Closing the question _is_ because it doesn't deserve an answer, because providing one anyway only encourages people to _keep posting bad questions_.