# How did I manage to up-vote this question?

Tags: bug, android-app, up-votes

I was looking through the hot questions on the Android app and came across something rather odd.

[image]

Apparently, *I* up-voted this question, however...

[image]

I'm not actually part of the site which **is** correct.

### How is this possible?

**Note:** I didn't actually up-vote this question, the time in the picture is the first time I saw the question.

Comment: Has the question been migrated?

Comment: @user000001 not sure. Just as a note, that is the first time I saw that question and I **didn't** up-vote it as the second image shows.

Comment: It's possible that this is a continuation of your [previous bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283368/up-vote-red-highlight-not-showing) and the app is just remembering the incorrect state of your upvote but applying it to a different post that has since been loaded. Did you upvote something just before loading this question? Does the upvote go away if you reload the question now?

Comment: @animuson AFAIR, I don't think I up-voted anything else, I was just flicking through the hot questions.

Comment: @user000001 No. The question is [this one](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76662/50015), which does not have a migration annotation.